# Looking To Get The Colour Of A Picture In Excel

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have a requirement where I need to get the colour of a picture in one of the cells.

Ideally I would like to do this via a piece of VBA Code, but I would be happy enough with a formula if one exists.

Please see attached screenshot.

In this scenario, I would like one of the following options

1. Replace Each of the Black Box Pictures with False and Replace the White Box Pictures with True
2. Have a formula that I could type into Column D which would describe the colour of the Picture.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Mark

[Screenshot Of Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kmmyu.jpg)

Comment: This is an image of a checkbox? Why not an actual checkbox? You can even tie one of those to a cell to have it report True/False based on what's checked without a formula or VBA.

Comment: Hi JNevill, Thanks for your reply. 

I am getting the text from an external source, and they copy across as pictures as oppose to checkboxes.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is a beast since we have to hit up a bunch of windows libraries to get the absolute position of the top-left of a cell, grab the pixel, figure out the color, and dump that back into the workbook.

I just did an "Assign Macro" to a picture in Cell D2 so when I click on it, this will stick that same color in Cell `A1`. You can monkey around with it to get it to do what you need, but all the necessary junk is here to do it.

```
#If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetPixel Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hDC As LongPtr, ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowDC Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetDC Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function ReleaseDC Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal hDC As Long) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetSystemMetrics Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetDeviceCaps Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hDC As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetCurrentThreadId Lib "kernel32" () As Long
#Else
    Private Declare Function GetPixel Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hDC As Long, ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function GetWindowDC Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function GetDC Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function ReleaseDC Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal hDC As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function GetSystemMetrics Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function GetDeviceCaps Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hDC As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function GetCurrentThreadId Lib "kernel32" () As Long
#End If

Option Explicit

Private Type RECT
    Left As Long
    Top As Long
    Right As Long
    Bottom As Long
End Type

Private Type POINTAPI
    x As Long
    y As Long
End Type


Private Function ScreenDPI(bVert As Boolean) As Long
    'in most cases this simply returns 96
    Static lDPI&(1), lDC&
    If lDPI(0) = 0 Then
        lDC = GetDC(0)
        lDPI(0) = GetDeviceCaps(lDC, 88&)    'horz
        lDPI(1) = GetDeviceCaps(lDC, 90&)    'vert
        lDC = ReleaseDC(0, lDC)
    End If
    ScreenDPI = lDPI(Abs(bVert))
End Function

Private Function PTtoPX(Points As Single, bVert As Boolean) As Long
    PTtoPX = Points * ScreenDPI(bVert) / 72
End Function

Private Sub GetRangeRect(ByVal rng As Range, ByRef rc As RECT)
    Dim wnd As Window

    'requires additional code to verify the range is visible
    'etc.

    Set wnd = rng.Parent.Parent.Windows(1)
    With rng
        rc.Left = PTtoPX(.Left * wnd.Zoom / 100, 0) _
                  + wnd.PointsToScreenPixelsX(0)
        rc.Top = PTtoPX(.Top * wnd.Zoom / 100, 1) _
                 + wnd.PointsToScreenPixelsY(0)
        rc.Right = PTtoPX(.Width * wnd.Zoom / 100, 0) _
                   + rc.Left
        rc.Bottom = PTtoPX(.Height * wnd.Zoom / 100, 1) _
                    + rc.Top
    End With
End Sub

Sub CellColor(cellRange As Range)

    Dim lColour As Long
    Dim lDC As Variant
    lDC = GetWindowDC(0)

    'Grab the pixel that we will use to determine the color
    Dim rc As RECT
    Dim xPos As Integer
    Dim yPos As Integer
    Call GetRangeRect(cellRange, rc)
    xPos = rc.Left
    yPos = rc.Top

    lColour = GetPixel(lDC, xPos, yPos)
    Debug.Print xPos, yPos, lColour

    Sheet1.Range("a1").Interior.Color = lColour

End Sub

Sub Picture1_Click()
    CellColor Sheet1.Range("D2")
End Sub
```